# Eclipse: Prevent "File Search" from opening different files in the same tab

Tags: eclipse

When I use the **File Search** option in Eclipse, when I get multiple results and I'm not sure about which file is the one I am looking for, I open a couple of them. However, *File Search* option "shares" the same tab and when opening the second file, it replaces the file that was opened first.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour and get each file to open in its own tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'Preferences' go to the 'General > Search' page.

The 'Reuse editors to show matches' option controls using a single / multiple editors for search results.